# iOS - Scrollview and equal widths does not work

Tags: ios, swift, view, autolayout, scrollview

I'm facing a problem with Autolayout. I want to setup a simple scrollview controller, with the following pattern View -> ScrollView -> View -> "All my content" explained everywhere when searching on the web.

Here is my Storyboard : 
[image]

In theory everything is correct, but the Equal Widths constraint seems to behave very strange. I made a videos for you to be able to see :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lAezdxg5L4E&feature=youtu.be

PS : The view controller is not linked to a *ViewController.swift, so there is no self-made code behind this controller.

How to solve that ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have laid out your constraints for the **wCompact hRegular** size class, which applies to all iPhones in *Portrait*. When you switch to landscape, none of the constraints are installed which explains your issues. Convert your constraints to **wAny hAny** and all will be good.

After recreating your problem, I did this to convert to **wAny hAny**:

1. I went to each constraint and turned off the tick mark next to **wC hR installed**.  You'll also need to do this for the ScrollView and Container as well.
2. Then I set the size class back to **wAny hAny**.
3. Then I went back to each constraint and ScrollView and Container and turned on the tick next to **installed** and deleted the *wC hR* one by clicking on the "x".

If you do this, your green Container view will appear in both *Portrait* and *Landscape* and it will scroll vertically.

---

Two hints:

1. If the reason you set *wCompact hRegular* was that you find it distracting to work with a square viewController, then click on the viewController in the Storyboard and set the *Simulated Metrics Size* to *iPhone 4.7-inch* in the *Attributes Inspector*.
2. You should really set *Equal Widths* between the Container and the ScrollView instead of setting *Equal Widths* between the Container and the top level view.  In your case it doesn't matter because the ScrollView and its SuperView have the same width.  But if your ScrollView wasn't the entire width of the screen, then you'd want to constrain the Container width to the ScrollView width to prevent horizontal scrolling.

[image: Demo in iPhone5s Simulator]

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem I did'nt know about w* and h* :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the contentView(**container** in your app) of the scrollView if doesn't work like that. 
eg. if you set contentView inside scrollview to equal width and height of the scroll view if wont work.

If subviews of containerView is complicated, normally I design contantView outside of scroll view. (see screen shot) and set it programmatically.

Or I just set auto-layouts equal width to both scrollView and container of scrollview too. (see screenshot)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see you use size class, possibly you don't have contraint for iphone landcape

Comment: That isn't answer to the question